# Display certain combinations in pivot

Tags: excel, pivot

[image]

How can I let the Pivot display only Jun-2016-Forecast for month 201701, Jul-2016-Forecast for month 201702 and Aug-2016-Forecast for month 201703 at the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way: add a column to your data matching your `Month` with `Forecast version` (so that `Version Jun-2016` matches with `201701`, `Version Jul-2016` matches with `201702` and `Version Aug-2016` matches with `2091703`). Column should contain `TRUE` where a match occurs and `FALSE` otherwise. Filter your pivot table on `TRUE` values in the added column.

Picture below illustrates the approach

[image]

I used a formula to generate my `Matched` column but, as an alternative,  could have used filtering on the source data to assign its values.

Comment: That means a lot of manual work if I have a big data so there is no other way to do it?

Comment: The formula used in cell F3 of the solution picture that can be copied down the column. I have shown that formula in the picture. The formula  you use will need to be appropriate to your own situation. If you think your situation will require excessive manual intervention
then ask a question about it (showing of course what you have already tried). Unless you have massive variation in the relationship between the forecast versions and forecast dates you want to restrict your output to, you should be able to develop an appropriate formula applicable to every row of your data.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that formula, my bad. However thanks for your help! :)